# JAVA, put the correct day depending on the month that is added

Tags: java

Put the correct day depending on the month that is added. In the case of the month and day, once the month has entered, the day will be requested. The text to be displayed on the screen must be: `day:`

Depending on the month, the limit values ​​for the day are indicated in this text.

For example, in the case of July: day (1-31):

in the case of June: day (1-30):

and in the case of February: day (1-29):

And in the other months, I left it at max 31, right now I have the code that every day has min 1 and max 31

I have it defined like this:

```
System.out.print (" month: ");
correctValue = reader.hasNextInt ();
if (correctValue) {
    month = reader.nextInt ();
    if ((month <MIN_MES || month> MAX_MES)) {
        dadaCorrecta = false;
        System.out.println ("you have the wrong value");
    } else {
```

THE MIN_MES is 1 and MAX_MES is 12

I understand that the best option would be to create a switch but I don't know how to do it, any help please, thank you very much

Comment: You need the year as well; Java has **multiple** `Date` types that can be used to solve this problem. But I assume this is for school, I will say that a `switch` is not the best option (have you learned about [Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)? Are you asking us to write the `else` for you?

Comment: Why do People keep calling it JAVA? It is not an acronym, the language is named after the coffee from the Java island in Indonesia. It is especially vexing for people calling themselves Java developers that don't even bother to capitalize the first letter of each sentence.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have an entire shelf of books stylized that way. "JAVA 2D Graphics", "Exploring JAVA", "JAVA Virtual Machine". I see a few "correct" examples as well. And a few that are just all caps.

Comment: It's kind of hard to understand what you're trying to achieve, it doesn't look like you've posted all of your code here. What's the input here? A month input by a user? The current month we're in?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Month.of( 2 ).maxLength()
```

> 29

## `Month` enum

To get the maximum days in a month, ask an object provided by the `Month` enum.

```
int monthNumber = 2 ;  // Entered by user. 1-12 for January to December. 
Month month = Month.of( monthNumber ) ;  // Retrieve one of the pre-defined enum objects.
int max = month.maxLength() ;
```

Get the localized name of the month. Specify a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms to use in localizing.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;  // Or, Locale.US or some such. 
String monthDescribed = month.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , locale ) + "( 1 - " + max + " )" ;
```

Without the context of a specific year, we cannot tell if February will have 28 or 29 days. So 29 is the maximum.